# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x19f2338f4) for URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurl

I am new in swift .I got this api from postman .I am trying to call this but getting app struct of this line

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
```

giving error at URL(string: url)! is :

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x19f2338f4)

Here is complete postman function

```
func apiCall(url:String)  {


    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

   //compiler struck on this line below

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      guard let data = data else {
        print(String(describing: error))
        semaphore.signal()
        return
      }
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
      semaphore.signal()
    }

    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()

}
```

It is giving error

Here is function call

```
 apiCall(url: urlEncode)
```

How i can free my code from this error ?
I have searched on internet and stackoverflow but did not resolved this issue.

Comment: Is there any error message in console, like "force unwrapping"? I'd tend to say that `URL(string: url)` is nil, and because you force unwrapped it with `!` (which means crash if it's nil because I assured you it wasn't)... What's the value of `url`? It has invalid characers, like spaces, etc that need to be percent escaped.

Comment: You got a bad URL. You might have to encode it. And don’t use semaphores to force an asynchronous task to become synchronous. Learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works or adopt the new `async/await` pattern of Swift 5.5

Comment: @Larme i have tested that url on Postman giving successful response

Comment: And remove or change the timeoutInterval argument, you don’t want to wait so long if there is a problem with the server or the connection.

Comment: @frincit In you try that URL into a WebBrowser, it will changes the spaces with "%20", I think Postman does too some hidden percent escaping. If you don't believe me, it's fine. If you don't want to just test: `if let urlAsURL = URL(string: url) { print("It's valid URL) } else { print("it needs some works for: \(url)}`?

Comment: @Larme ,it is printing "it needs some works for:"... Please tell me what work i need ?

Comment: I have matched this url with android app url they are identically the same ...This url is working for android but not for ios

Comment: The key word is "percent escape". There are invalid characters that need to be percent escape in your string. It's fine if you don't want to share your string, but then it's up to you to find which character is invalid (for future knowledge), and look yourself for "Swift percent escape URL") that should give you answers on your favorite Search Engine. Android might allow them or just percent escape them itself, like Safari.app might do...